# Average value plotting in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a question regarding plotting a line that is the average of a selection within a column. This might be formulated unclearly therefore I will explain it further.

Here is the head of my data:

```
structure(list(Location = c("Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", 
"Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", 
"Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", 
"Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", "Burundi", 
"Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", 
"Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", 
"Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", 
"Comoros", "Comoros", "Comoros", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", 
"Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", 
"Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", 
"Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", "Djibouti", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Croatia", 
"Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
"Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
"Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
"Croatia", "Croatia", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", 
"Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", 
"Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", 
"Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", 
"Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", 
"Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", 
"Malta", "Malta", "Malta", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", 
"Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", 
"Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", 
"Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", 
"Montenegro", "Montenegro", "Montenegro", "North Macedonia", 
"North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", 
"North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", 
"North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", 
"North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", 
"North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", "North Macedonia", 
"Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
"Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
"Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
"Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", 
"Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", 
"Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", 
"Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", 
"Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", 
"Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", 
"Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", 
"Slovenia", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
"Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
"Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
"Spain", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Luxembourg", 
"Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", 
"Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", 
"Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", 
"Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
"Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
"Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
"Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
"Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", 
"United States of America"), Time = c("1950", "1955", "1960", 
"1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", 
"2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", 
"2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", 
"1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", 
"2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", 
"1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", 
"1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", 
"2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", 
"1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", 
"2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", 
"2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", 
"1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", 
"2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", 
"1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", 
"2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", 
"2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", 
"1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", 
"1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", 
"1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", 
"2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", 
"1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", 
"2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", 
"2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", 
"1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", 
"2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", 
"1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", 
"1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", 
"2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", 
"1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", 
"2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", 
"2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", 
"1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", 
"2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", 
"1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", 
"2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", 
"2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", 
"1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", 
"1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", 
"1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", 
"2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", 
"1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", 
"2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", 
"2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", 
"1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", 
"2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", 
"1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", 
"1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", 
"2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", 
"1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", 
"2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", 
"2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", 
"1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", 
"2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", 
"1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", 
"2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", 
"2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", 
"1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", 
"1950", "1955", "1960", "1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", 
"1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", 
"2030", "2035", "2040", "2045", "2050", "1950", "1955", "1960", 
"1965", "1970", "1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", 
"2005", "2010", "2015", "2020", "2025", "2030", "2035", "2040", 
"2045", "2050"), `Dependency Ratio` = c(0.285062713797035, 0.29073482428115, 
0.297914597815293, 0.305762081784387, 0.312607944732297, 0.318816762530813, 
0.285017421602787, 0.270286760219646, 0.257575757575758, 0.252127659574468, 
0.237901171676006, 0.23044925124792, 0.232296492389146, 0.230748074807481, 
0.22585128561501, 0.218725566849101, 0.225801123224315, 0.24879977407512, 
0.282022886674049, 0.309271666306462, 0.324892908138981, 0.296875, 
0.304347826086957, 0.305555555555556, 0.306666666666667, 0.316455696202532, 
0.32183908045977, 0.323809523809524, 0.3, 0.287769784172662, 
0.268292682926829, 0.252577319587629, 0.256637168141593, 0.261363636363636, 
0.267326732673267, 0.277456647398844, 0.29156010230179, 0.308219178082192, 
0.330595482546201, 0.359404096834264, 0.384615384615385, 0.408227848101266, 
0.227272727272727, 0.208333333333333, 0.233333333333333, 0.214285714285714, 
0.241379310344828, 0.272727272727273, 0.239669421487603, 0.25503355704698, 
0.242857142857143, 0.263157894736842, 0.265454545454545, 0.264516129032258, 
0.276595744680851, 0.295942720763723, 0.326086956521739, 0.369168356997972, 
0.434697855750487, 0.496240601503759, 0.572477064220184, 0.63768115942029, 
0.70197486535009, 0.623733393379869, 0.690404797601199, 0.758585907104088, 
0.809244917715392, 0.798864862329378, 0.829428920876846, 0.81582562505724, 
0.768988705922924, 0.732905808348991, 0.737049232993334, 0.794927123198437, 
0.806297899376564, 0.83949020353814, 0.906580537926866, 0.972976037493386, 
1.0261316089768, 1.06147339802892, 1.1071777894816, 1.16793864145499, 
1.21431844215349, 1.23692941311063, 0.455555555555556, 0.412451361867704, 
0.403061224489796, 0.4, 0.395256916996047, 0.375283446712018, 
0.364161849710983, 0.356907894736842, 0.371096586782861, 0.439454691259022, 
0.45679012345679, 0.542721518987342, 0.668890742285238, 0.770519262981575, 
0.839090143218197, 0.899050905953408, 0.941228851291184, 0.979908675799087, 
1.11242603550296, 1.3021978021978, 1.49384236453202, 0.330339321357285, 
0.328384279475983, 0.342391304347826, 0.352898550724638, 0.316883116883117, 
0.319347319347319, 0.369047619047619, 0.419176706827309, 0.511066398390342, 
0.561017929438982, 0.597271648873072, 0.672413793103448, 0.762285012285012, 
0.908636688079943, 1.01527883880825, 1.10887096774194, 1.17238493723849, 
1.29084380610413, 1.39980544747082, 1.46514047866805, 1.62980209545984, 
0.490886998784933, 0.499712147380541, 0.541057367829021, 0.576666666666667, 
0.534562211981567, 0.566733067729084, 0.621728395061728, 0.677974434611603, 
0.723645320197044, 0.741039878849066, 0.779131355932203, 0.851086956521739, 
0.945930563460444, 1.04548211036992, 1.11026131293818, 1.17722371967655, 
1.2705798138869, 1.37337413925019, 1.45558272208639, 1.51688311688312, 
1.60634328358209, 0.42596599690881, 0.43540125213432, 0.475549450549451, 
0.53781512605042, 0.641018306636156, 0.662430939226519, 0.694815195071869, 
0.750815558343789, 0.780359281437126, 0.728492333901193, 0.738745980707395, 
0.769169960474308, 0.876324324324324, 0.987006960556845, 1.13533266129032, 
1.29231610609789, 1.43598716827063, 1.58487027195999, 1.66163934426229, 
1.70723345903325, 1.76822633297062, 0.504146268358477, 0.541452395828327, 
0.601318744326055, 0.67049164586134, 0.645025752236378, 0.693630744423542, 
0.729160265133225, 0.737934504591387, 0.763757733637252, 0.77666837681045, 
0.849441397521836, 0.88956587966489, 0.958033133878781, 1.08344571813891, 
1.24790960451977, 1.42383848212114, 1.54249335242381, 1.60884731250991, 
1.67227815371073, 1.73982188295165, 1.79565111463028, 0.45, 0.541284403669725, 
0.568807339449541, 0.592920353982301, 0.566929133858268, 0.57037037037037, 
0.570422535211268, 0.525641025641026, 0.559006211180124, 0.606060606060606, 
0.702380952380952, 0.804733727810651, 0.900584795321637, 0.96045197740113, 
1, 1.06857142857143, 1.18674698795181, 1.32051282051282, 1.45890410958904, 
1.58695652173913, 1.61940298507463, 0.518248175182482, 0.44311377245509, 
0.401041666666667, 0.384259259259259, 0.429268292682927, 0.408510638297872, 
0.434782608695652, 0.468864468864469, 0.553435114503817, 0.5625, 
0.610486891385768, 0.706106870229008, 0.766283524904215, 0.828125, 
0.852140077821012, 0.904382470119522, 0.959349593495935, 1.04255319148936, 
1.1057268722467, 1.16438356164384, 1.21800947867299, 0.402083333333333, 
0.351005484460695, 0.356896551724138, 0.374183006535948, 0.344332855093257, 
0.360931435963777, 0.399761336515513, 0.439953810623557, 0.484641638225256, 
0.530092592592593, 0.550276243093923, 0.606093579978237, 0.659139784946237, 
0.712754555198285, 0.784378437843784, 0.859908883826879, 0.961399276236429, 
1.08376288659794, 1.21161825726141, 1.33233979135618, 1.40220820189274, 
0.451091579245818, 0.48436202601716, 0.531223980016653, 0.595107913669065, 
0.641002415458937, 0.666288630564219, 0.699228107532606, 0.718059436118872, 
0.744538232373386, 0.73600185099491, 0.758300132802125, 0.791576673866091, 
0.900698040981761, 1.03331712062257, 1.15812629399586, 1.3178531701891, 
1.47004470938897, 1.57367758186398, 1.62340216322517, 1.65985003408316, 
1.70770877944325, 0.462976022566996, 0.461986412164348, 0.490483619344774, 
0.502589095339628, 0.45667770419426, 0.484188698807672, 0.558421459891669, 
0.625871417505809, 0.653154294400811, 0.633915918752952, 0.715534465534466, 
0.814883969058416, 0.862980114410242, 0.917105627945661, 0.940231181279955, 
0.996174220129488, 1.0702736318408, 1.14830789648308, 1.25431034482759, 
1.35054347826087, 1.42928660826033, 0.485668789808917, 0.531446540880503, 
0.587326120556414, 0.604826546003017, 0.539944903581267, 0.551232166018158, 
0.60253164556962, 0.599765258215962, 0.609810479375697, 0.654708520179372, 
0.672113289760349, 0.764705882352941, 0.852348993288591, 0.969375736160188, 
1.10453400503778, 1.23655913978495, 1.39080459770115, 1.50829562594268, 
1.58869701726845, 1.58851674641148, 1.5475040257649, 0.45096449991895, 
0.485273382422059, 0.528641571194763, 0.569375807800502, 0.590145905125009, 
0.626715720956559, 0.671985334057577, 0.710840248962656, 0.70571045902837, 
0.701102397999773, 0.705408271474019, 0.703616427815716, 0.746339881393625, 
0.892810259517318, 1.04686061000054, 1.25253543680683, 1.47627961014652, 
1.63245169247636, 1.70394036208733, 1.74231107205624, 1.76694177330204, 
0.664967720013592, 0.771232381640766, 0.854947526236882, 0.861375274323336, 
0.771623931623932, 0.780627742153223, 0.761330290185849, 0.713587786259542, 
0.698015530629853, 0.704488430443267, 0.742937062937063, 0.767754318618042, 
0.845047039291644, 0.951729910714286, 1.05059355568118, 1.1343023255814, 
1.19477434679335, 1.29493514515133, 1.38862256311921, 1.47998676811115, 
1.50637156270959, 0.653333333333333, 0.713670613562971, 0.774574409665019, 
0.819175777964676, 0.74488188976378, 0.762913223140496, 0.756763464879623, 
0.747975226298237, 0.741578218735579, 0.732797140303843, 0.793252792341008, 
0.845698680018207, 0.903203971119134, 0.962938005390836, 1.03583579042867, 
1.10442600276625, 1.15349052242256, 1.2015306122449, 1.24695977549111, 
1.28524203069658, 1.29246397354122, 0.668781435756744, 0.718653206378341, 
0.768128403554027, 0.790242542514636, 0.684017631618048, 0.694005861775551, 
0.706155738825352, 0.705033469529688, 0.690188974432871, 0.679956007698653, 
0.766507253948479, 0.844177255911211, 0.919052240012939, 1.01370089138329, 
1.10321410494348, 1.18409305519787, 1.21603858136657, 1.25839141403344, 
1.30112408127972, 1.31867558877205, 1.33369798275938, 0.632701740240543, 
0.724778517958931, 0.788812046468845, 0.825566857027, 0.749944255088714, 
0.74036005731016, 0.736194267999878, 0.7178108469453, 0.755979369757425, 
0.788378363197214, 0.821155540398443, 0.8783631802059, 0.982105676091614, 
1.12999649089227, 1.22910176105992, 1.27003046840995, 1.31264375708057, 
1.38770053475936, 1.45860177447263, 1.48707559557306, 1.50141404876557, 
0.57037037037037, 0.642335766423358, 0.712121212121212, 0.753731343283582, 
0.72463768115942, 0.695364238410596, 0.685534591194969, 0.674698795180723, 
0.664772727272727, 0.654255319148936, 0.67005076142132, 0.707920792079208, 
0.713656387665198, 0.728346456692913, 0.770609318996416, 0.851063829787234, 
0.919014084507042, 1.00350877192982, 1.07317073170732, 1.15384615384615, 
1.18213058419244, 0.501072194424589, 0.551740139211137, 0.601626016260163, 
0.629208663950247, 0.607218683651805, 0.605936722360469, 0.597144732523794, 
0.590328467153285, 0.582565556343019, 0.606010703993413, 0.695511467567187, 
0.775706295712032, 0.87560724274989, 0.98951367781155, 1.11580274145265, 
1.18967166082244, 1.21868026777176, 1.25217251367879, 1.30642232128116, 
1.35472400948188, 1.38364671381749, 0.573443579766537, 0.61927255550307, 
0.670212765957447, 0.668792517006803, 0.630526720492118, 0.655352480417755, 
0.689925373134328, 0.684229012996136, 0.672912557527942, 0.685086342229199, 
0.753196930946292, 0.788246268656716, 0.839189994044074, 0.900601546834718, 
1.02421943390721, 1.11124225435232, 1.17662721893491, 1.26462646264626, 
1.3292131444076, 1.37240132570051, 1.38298507462687, 0.479648154536047, 
0.481302586475538, 0.49763644177052, 0.52930056710775, 0.527985739750446, 
0.524976633087548, 0.523086888128065, 0.517169701504947, 0.519917582417582, 
0.552762350190003, 0.622634747706422, 0.705444849845636, 0.800479452054795, 
0.913492927094668, 0.957950065703022, 0.997821909032671, 1.03197855628974, 
1.08186954919543, 1.12475751697381, 1.18854400777501, 1.22220883292161, 
0.521763077413651, 0.577066077145031, 0.619842347703121, 0.650062031393279, 
0.653649312996344, 0.643269617128753, 0.624897309776109, 0.581845001913902, 
0.562815557644765, 0.569633847844548, 0.615921135290991, 0.689418107573534, 
0.784417422838647, 0.855236876599463, 0.898765168445058, 0.921628370143575, 
0.93556708480259, 0.968336413124906, 1.01659552598895, 1.06991528460645, 
1.1028605253211)), row.names = c(NA, -525L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So basically I want to plot a line representing the dependency ratio for all countries against years.So that it will eventually look similar to this:
[Example results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku2dC.png)

However, I find it really hard to do so. I can plot all the countries, but than I have no average or selection of certain countries. I tried several things with the ggplot, such as hline. But I cant find anything similar regarding my question where people plot the average of a made selection.

Hopefully my question is clear and that someone is able to help me.

Thanking in advance,
Cas

Comment: My dataset is too large to do anything like dput(data) even if I do dput(data[1:4]

Comment: I want to be helped into the direction that I can so myself, but if I cannot find anything anywhere and whereas I am trying to upload the file but failing. I thought maybe people with great R knowledge can look at it and help me into the right direction!

Comment: Have you tried using pivot_longer() to get your data into a tidy format? After doing so, you can group_by() age or countries and calculate averages.

Comment: I am trying now, but is it possible to group_by(country=c('..", etc.) Because then it is possible to group for OECD countries and then take the mean of that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using the tidyverse:

I got the list of OECD countries from [here](https://www.oecd.org/newsroom/global-oecd-welcomes-colombia-as-its-37th-member.htm).

```
library(tidyverse)
 OECD <- c("Austria","Australia","Belgium","Canada","Chile","Colombia","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Israel","Italy","Japan","Korea","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Mexico","Netherlands","New Zealand","Norway","Poland","Portugal","Slovak Republic","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Turkey","United Kingdom","United States of America")

data %>%
   mutate(OECD = factor(Location %in% OECD, labels = c("NonOECD","OECD"))) %>%
   group_by(OECD, Time) %>%
   summarise(Mean = mean(`Dependency Ratio`)) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = Mean, names_from = OECD) %>%
   mutate(Total = sum(NonOECD, OECD, na.rm = TRUE))  -> newdata

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = filter(newdata, Time <= 2020),
            aes(x = Time, y = Total, group = 1, color = "Total"),lty = 1) +
  geom_line(data = filter(newdata, Time >= 2020), 
            aes(x = Time, y = Total, group = 1, color = "Total"),lty = 3) +
  geom_line(data = filter(newdata, Time <= 2020), 
            aes(x = Time, y = OECD, group = 1, color = "OECD"),lty = 1) +
  geom_line(data = filter(newdata, Time >= 2020), 
            aes(x = Time, y = OECD, group = 1, color = "OECD"),lty = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Total = "black", OECD = "red"),
                     labels = c(Total = "All Countries", OECD = "OECD Countries")) +
  labs(color = '', x = "Year", y = "Mean Dependency Ratio") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: As for the dotted line: i tried adding the following: 

%>% mutate(Dash = Time > 2020)  %>%
  group_by(Time, Dash) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = filter(Total, !Dash), linetype='solid', color = "Total")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = filter(Total, Dash), linetype='dashed', color = "Total")) +

But that gives an error.

Comment: The problem with trying to add the line type to the data is that the 2020 data points need to be in both lines. Additionally, the grouping status of the tibble you pass to `ggplot` has no influence on the `group` aesthetic.

Comment: Ah I see, now I get it. Thanks again!!